# Stepper form data

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to dotnet core mvc. So I am asking a suggestion. I have 2 stepper form. I need to get data from this two form , do some validation and finally save this to db. How can I make view and get data from view to controller ? Should I make two view page and two controller ? Or one will be enough ?

Way to achieve this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two separate view pages and two corresponding action methods in the controller (one for each step of the form). You can use `TempData` or `Session` to store data. Then, in the last action method, you can perform all the necessary validations and save the data to your database. Alternatively, you can use a single view page and use javascript to hide/show different parts of the form based on the current step. Finally, you can use a single action method in the controller to handle the submission and processing of the entire form data.

Tell me if this helps :)

Comment: I was thinking like this. But not sure which one will be efficient and easy to manage ?